# Integrating sampled points of periodic square signal in python

Tags: python

I want to work out the integration between consecutive sampled points (i.e point i and point i+1 all the way to the end). I managed to do this for a sine wave using the definite integral, unsure how to do it for this signal, any thoughts?
[plot of periodic square signal with stars for points I want to integrate between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlnKG.png)

Comment: The integral for a square wave is just `((max amplitude) - (min amplitude)) x ((end time)-(start time)) x (duty cycle)`.  Right?  If it was on all the time, it would be a rectangle.  You know the area of a rectangle.  If it's on 50% of the time, then it's half of a rectangle.

Comment: Yep, I want an integral function that can work for a variable sampling value though, not necessarily always half the period.

Comment: any sampling value*

Comment: Well, do you know in advance that it's a square wave or a sine wave?  The solution for a sampled signal of unknown shape is quite different.  And I didn't say "sampling at half the period".  What I said was "duty cycle".  If you know the duty cycle is 50% (so the "off" time equals the "on" time), then what I wrote works fine.

Comment: its a square wave like in the picture I linked in the question. The period of the square wave is fixed but the sampling period is variable. So, the function needs to take inputs of a and b for the upper and lower bounds and integrate over the square wave portion

Comment: That doesn't change anything. IF YOU KNOW IT IS A SQUARE WAVE, then your sampling can tell you the max and min amplitude, and if the sampling is regular, it can tell you the duty cycle, based on what percentage is high and what percentage is low..  That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the signal have only straight lines. In this case, you can calculate the linear function y=ax+b based on two adjacent points and then calculate the definite integral for the function in the range given by the points.

Comment: the signal is a periodic square wave so should have no gradient a, it does look like it has a slope in the image but its definitely a square wave.

Comment: You can always use monte carlo integration ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude script that integrates the data in your sample,  In this case, you have 34 samples at a spacing of dt=0.01.

```
data = [
2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0.5, 2, 0, 2, 0,
2, 0.5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, .5, 2, 0,
2, 0, 2, .5, 0, 2, 0, .5, 2, 0,
2, 0, 2, 2
]

spacing = 0.01
minx = 0
miny = min(data)
maxx = spacing * len(data)
maxy = max(data)
ave = sum(data)/len(data)
print("Min",minx)
print("Max",maxx)
print("Ave",ave)
timespan = maxx-minx
span = maxy-miny
area = span * (timespan) * (ave/span)
print("Duty cycle", ave/span)
print("Timespan", maxx-minx )
print("Area",area)
```

Output:

```
Min 0
Max 0.34
Ave 1.0147058823529411
Duty cycle 0.5073529411764706
Timespan 0.34
Area 0.34500000000000003
```

And for a 50% duty cycle square wave with an amplitude of 2, the integral should be equal to the timespan.

Comment: is this for the first integration?

Comment: This integrates the entire waveform.  Unlike a sine wave, you cannot guess what a square wave looks like.  If two consecutive points are 0, then the integral is 0.  If two consecutive points are high, then the integral is amplitude x interval.  If two consecutive points are different, then it is impossible to know, unless you know exactly when the transition occurred.